# @ConditionalOnClass for `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot library that adds autoconfiguration. I am already using `@ConditionalOnClass` successfully to only activate parts of the library if Spring Security is on the classpath for example.

Currently, my library requires `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency, and I would like to make this optional. I added `@ConditionalOnClass` like this:

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnClass(name = "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException")
    public ConstraintViolationApiExceptionHandler constraintViolationApiExceptionHandler(ErrorHandlingProperties properties,
                                                                                         HttpStatusMapper httpStatusMapper,
                                                                                         ErrorCodeMapper errorCodeMapper,
                                                                                         ErrorMessageMapper errorMessageMapper) {
        return new ConstraintViolationApiExceptionHandler(properties, httpStatusMapper, errorCodeMapper, errorMessageMapper);
    }
```

But when running in an application, I get this error:

```
2022-03-26 11:00:14.028 ERROR 3171 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration$AnnotationConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.server.reactive.HttpHandler]: Factory method 'httpHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'globalErrorWebExceptionHandler' defined in class path resource [io/github/wimdeblauwe/errorhandlingspringbootstarter/ReactiveErrorHandlingConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'globalErrorWebExceptionHandler' parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'constraintViolationApiExceptionHandler' defined in class path resource [io/github/wimdeblauwe/errorhandlingspringbootstarter/ReactiveErrorHandlingConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.github.wimdeblauwe.errorhandlingspringbootstarter.handler.ConstraintViolationApiExceptionHandler] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.wimdeblauwe.examples.reactiveerrorhandling.ReactiveErrorHandlingApplication.main(ReactiveErrorHandlingApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.server.reactive.HttpHandler]: Factory method 'httpHandler' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'globalErrorWebExceptionHandler' defined in class path resource [io/github/wimdeblauwe/errorhandlingspringbootstarter/ReactiveErrorHandlingConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'globalErrorWebExceptionHandler' parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'constraintViolationApiExceptionHandler' defined in class path resource [io/github/wimdeblauwe/errorhandlingspringbootstarter/ReactiveErrorHandlingConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.github.wimdeblauwe.errorhandlingspringbootstarter.handler.ConstraintViolationApiExceptionHandler] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'globalErrorWebExceptionHandler' defined in class path resource [io/github/wimdeblauwe/errorhandlingspringbootstarter/ReactiveErrorHandlingConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'globalErrorWebExceptionHandler' parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'constraintViolationApiExceptionHandler' defined in class path resource [io/github/wimdeblauwe/errorhandlingspringbootstarter/ReactiveErrorHandlingConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.github.wimdeblauwe.errorhandlingspringbootstarter.handler.ConstraintViolationApiExceptionHandler] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$1.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(WebHttpHandlerBuilder.java:178) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration$AnnotationConfig.httpHandler(HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'constraintViolationApiExceptionHandler' defined in class path resource [io/github/wimdeblauwe/errorhandlingspringbootstarter/ReactiveErrorHandlingConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.github.wimdeblauwe.errorhandlingspringbootstarter.handler.ConstraintViolationApiExceptionHandler] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1460) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [io.github.wimdeblauwe.errorhandlingspringbootstarter.handler.ConstraintViolationApiExceptionHandler] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@251a69d7]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ConstraintViolation
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ConstraintViolation
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Some helpful links for others: [the reference docs on auto configuration conditions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.condition-annotations) and [the likely library involved](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/error-handling-spring-boot-starter/blob/develop/src/main/java/io/github/wimdeblauwe/errorhandlingspringbootstarter/reactive/ReactiveErrorHandlingConfiguration.java).

Comment: Have you tried the note on ConditionalOnClass "Extra care is required when placed on \@Bean methods, consider isolating the condition in a separate \@Configuration class"?
And from what I read you can use the actual class as argument, and make the dependency optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to put `@ConditionalOnClass` on the class level. Otherwise Spring Boot still has to load the configuration class to analyze it and this will fail if not all dependencies are on the classpath. If you put `@ConditionalOnClass` on the configuration class instead, Spring Boot can read this information without actually loading the class and skip class loading if the class declared in `@ConditionalOnClass` is not on the classpath.

In this case you could even reference the real class in `@ConditionalOnClass` instead of the class name as string. Just make sure that your dependency is optional so that it's not included as transitive dependency of your library.

By the way, this was the short answer. The long version can be found here: https://youtu.be/N39hpGAT43s ;-) I really like this presentation. Learned a lot from it.